# Define TypeScript union type that can be globally extended

Tags: typescript

Consider I have an exported array that can be extended from multiple modules, e.g.:

```js
// values.ts
export const values = [];

export function useValue(value) {
  // ...
}
```

```js
// module-1.ts
import { values } from './values.js';

values.push('foo', 'bar');

// @todo extend type
```

```js
// module-2.ts
import { values } from './values.js';

values.push('baz');

// @todo extend type
```

```js
// module-3.ts
import { useValue } from './values.js';

// (TS ERROR) should only accept: "foo" | "bar" | "baz".
useValue('qux');
```

Is it possible to create an (ambient?) union type that can be extended by individual modules by adding new values to the existing type?

I've tried to use interfaces and triple-slash directives to achieve the desired result, but without much luck.

What I want to create is some kind of a tags system, where core functionality is provided by the library modules, while users can introduce their own tags in various parts of their application or even in other libraries. The core library, however, should see the introduced tags and validate all the function calls correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I know of to get that kind of extension of a type in your library is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) with an `interface`. (Caveat: I'm very much only a journeyman in TypeScript.)

Your library's types could look something like this (in your `index.d.ts` or similar):

```typescript
declare module "yourlib" {
    interface PossibleValues {
        // Starts off empty (unless you have some defaults in `values`)
    }
    type Value = keyof PossibleValues;

    const values: Value[];

    function useValue(value: Value): void/* Or whatever it returns */;
}
```

Notice how the type of `Value` is derived from the contents of the `PossibleValues` interface. That's the key bit. We don't care about the type of the properties in `PossibleValues`, just their names.

Then, `module-1.ts` would look like this:

```typescript
import { values } from "yourlib";

declare module "yourlib" {
    interface PossibleValues {
        foo: true;
        bar: true;
    }
}

values.push("foo", "bar");
```

That uses declaration merging to add `foo` and `bar` to the interface, and pushes the actual strings into `values`. The `push` call is valid because `"foo"` and `"bar"` are part of `Value` as a result of being added to `PossibleValues`.

Then `module-2.ts` does the same thing:

```typescript
import { values } from "yourlib";

declare module "yourlib" {
    interface PossibleValues {
        baz: true;
    }
}

values.push("baz");
```

And finally, let's test the usage in `module-3.ts`:

```typescript
import { useValue } from "yourlib";

useValue("foo"); // OK
useValue("bar"); // OK
useValue("baz"); // OK
useValue("qux"); // Error: Argument of type '"qux"' is not assignable to 'Value'
```

This is, unfortunately, inherently a bit fragile in that it would be easy for an extension module to augment the interface but fail to add the value to `values`, making the type system and runtime get slightly out of sync. (Fortunately, they can't make the other mistake — the type of `values` wouldn't let them push the string if they haven't augmented the interface.)

---

In a comment you asked how to test this in a project without making `yourlib` a separate library. You can do that by just making `yourlib` a module and using `declare module` to extend it:

`yourlib.ts`:

```typescript
export interface PossibleValues {
    // Starts off empty (unless you have some defaults in `values`)
}
type Value = keyof PossibleValues;

export const values: Value[] = [];

export function useValue(value: Value): void {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Note this is no longer a `.d.ts` file, we don't have it wrapped in `declare module "yourlib"`, and we provide the actual runtime values for the array and function.

`module-1.ts`:

```typescript
import { values } from "./yourlib";

declare module "./yourlib" {
    interface PossibleValues {
        foo: true;
        bar: true;
    }
}

values.push("foo", "bar");
```

`module-2.ts`:

```typescript
import { values } from "./yourlib";

declare module "./yourlib" {
    interface PossibleValues {
        baz: true;
    }
}

values.push("baz");
```

`module-3.ts` is unchanged except for the `import` ('`from "./yourlib"` instead of `from "yourlib"`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to use a similar approach with some differences. Namely, is it possible to use this without extracting the "yourlib" package? I would like to test it in a single project initially. Also, can you please explain the reason for adding the `__base__` property? What would happen if the interface will be left empty? Aren't merging gonna work?

Comment: TIL you can extend a normal module. :-) I've added an example to the answer. Re the `__base__` property: Because TypeScript's type system is structural, empty interfaces can be really problematic, so I usually shy away from them. But that may be overkill in this case, I'm 95% sure you can just remove the `__base__` stuff and it should still work (at least, it did in my quick test).

Comment: FYI it works fine without a `__base__` so I guess you can delete it from the answer :)

Comment: @SlavaFominII - Yeah, I'd tested it before posting the comment above. But you're right, it's an unnecessary complication, since we only use the interface for its keys.